# Firebase functions not working with axios get function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, axios

I don't understand why my axios.get(firebase project / .json) file not working properly.
What am I doing wrong here, any idea???

```
import axios from "axios";
class allClass extends Component {
  state = {
    item: [],
    data: [],
    loaded: false,
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://foodie-ghar-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.json")
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ data: data.data, loaded: true });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log("Some Error"))
      .then(console.log("Lets try this "));
  }
```

Comment: Can you try `.catch((err) => console.log("err"))` instead of logging Some error and share the error ?

Comment: Also: if you `console.log(data)` inside `then(...)`, what does it output?

Comment: basically the problem occur in axios.get(.../.json)